# Hint for $\sum\limits_{l\text{ odd}}\dbinom{n}{l} = \dbinom{n}{l} + \dbinom{n}{3} + ... = 2^{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

$\sum\limits_{l\text{ odd}}\dbinom{n}{l} = \dbinom{n}{l} + \dbinom{n}{3} + ... = 2^{n-1}$

This has to be done via induction, but i'm not sure how. The base case is easily proved by taking n = 1. The induction argument, however, requires the $\sum\limits_{l\text{ odd}}\dbinom{n}{l} = 2^{n-1}$ to become $\sum\limits_{l\text{ odd}}\dbinom{n+1}{l} = 2^n$. I'm looking for only a slight hint as to how this may be done.

Comment: "This has to be done via induction" <--- why?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615343/the-equation-to-be-proved-is-sum-j-0n-1j-dbinomnj-dbinomn0

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The problem is in a induction part of the book, and all the other questions have used induction. So it's safe to assume that the author wanted to use induction.

Comment: And your accepted answer doesn't involve induction.

Comment: That's true. I was confused about which answer to select, but in the end i asked for a hint for how to solve it, and Rob gave that hint. Then i asked him to elaborate and since there was only one step left, he had to give away the main proof itself. I thought that it should quality to be the correct answer because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Try expanding $(1+1)^n$ and $(1-1)^n$ using the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

---

**More after comments**
$$
\begin{align}
2^n
&=(1+1)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
0^n
&=(1-1)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$ and divide by $2$:
$$
2^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1-(-1)^k}2\tag{3}
$$
Consider what $\frac{1-(-1)^k}2$ is for even and odd $k$.

Comment: I'm afraid i already did that in a previous exercise. I did consider it here and i managed to get to subtracting the sum from 0 to n with twice of the sum from 0 to n/2, but i got stuck after that and wasn't sure how to proceed.

Comment: @AayushAgrawal: I have added some more explanation

Comment: Thank you. I think there's a typo in the third equation though, you wrote $(-1)^n$. Should't it be raised to k?

Comment: @AayushAgrawal: fixed

Answer (score 1):

One way: $\binom{n+1}{l} = \binom{n}{l} + \binom{n}{l-1}$, and note that if we assume $\sum_{l \text{ odd}} \binom{n}{l} = 2^{n-1}$ we also have $\sum_{l \text{ even}} \binom{n}{l} = 2^{n-1}$, as $\sum_{l} \binom{n}{l} = 2^{n}$.

This will allow you to use an induction proof.